# Country name from an Ip address with free IP geolocation webservice

Tags: php, ip-address, ip-geolocation

First of all thanks to all ....

I read that i can use  the free IP geolocation webservice to get Country name from an Ip address. But how i get the response to my site , Actually this is what i look , In my site there is a need of displaying the country name from Ip address. Can uou please tell in detail... How can i display the country Name from that site ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.maxmind.com/app/php

You need to install the php module and then use the following code to get the country name:

`$country_name = apache_note("GEOIP_COUNTRY_NAME");`

Answer (score 4):

[`geoip_country_code_by_name`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.geoip-country-code-by-name.php) can give you the country for an arbitrary IP address or hostname (not just the one from the current visitor as `apache_note("GEOIP_COUNTRY_NAME")` does), it uses the same MaxMind database. There is also the `geoip_country_name_by_name` function if you want the full country name rather than the ISO code.

Answer (score 0):

Have checked this functionality in [Oplim](https://oplim.com/oplimation/uy4sz1rmu/run-a-javascript-code-if-visitor-is-from-canada)? It is free for up to 500k pageviews, and you can set your code and custom condition (country, or even areas such as all the EU).

[image]

Disclosure: I am among the service developers.