# Javascript: find out current page's locale

Tags: javascript, localization, internationalization, locale

How do I find, using Javascript, the locale of the page the script is running in?

Comment: Or duplicate of [Is it possible to run code if visitor is from a certain country](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3696218/is-it-possible-to-run-code-if-visitor-is-from-a-certain-country)

Comment: Why do you want to know?

Comment: Use a session cookie to store this information from the server side and read it on client side; I just want to warn you, that "Localized" functionality (i.e. toLocaleString()) works: a) inconsistently, b) mostly incorrectly on different web browsers, so unless you need this information as an input to eg. jQuery Globalization plugin or to request something from the server, you should refrain from using it.

Answer (score -2):

Did you mean the url of page running? You can get that as below:

var loc = window.location.href;

Comment: More likely the country/language setting